# Commerce Backoffice does not delete product variation TYPE

Tags: commerce

When I add a new "Product variation TYPES" with Backoffice it creates a new "Content type" in Drupal. But if I want to delete some "Product variation type" it does not delete the matched content type. Is it OK? Do I have to delete it by myself? Or am I going something wrong?

Comment: +1 ! Though "Thank you" is consider as "noise". Rules around here say that "that" does not help anything to better explain the question (I find that a pitty, because I was taught to always say thank you ...). So don't be surprised if some day somebody EDITs your question to remove that (maybe edit it your self to avoid that ...). Back to "thinking" about an answer now (may only be tomorrow or so, sorry).